# How to intentionally get slashed?

Tags: prysm, slashings

for a project we're working on, I'd like to simulate slashing locally. I'm using a docker-compose set up based on https://github.com/OffchainLabs/eth-pos-devnet/blob/master/docker-compose.yml (so basically geth + prysm). I tried adding another validator with the same key, but still didn't manage to get slashed. Without changing the code of Prysm and building a Docker image, how can I get slashed?